# How do i create a button to another page for my app

Tags: java, android, xml, button

i was just wondering how i would make a button on my page so that it would go to another page for my app. I am a beginner so if you could explain how it all works and where it goes it would help a lot.
PS i am using android studio if that makes a difference and this is the code i have so far in my fragment_main.xml. I have not entered any code into the .java

```
<TextView android:text="@string/hello_world"
    android:id="@id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/firstbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"/>
```

Comment: If I were you, I'd declare the button in Java and set the location in Java so you can pass it from fragment to fragment.

Comment: Do you need start a new page or a new activity??

Answer (score 0):

You can declare views and objects dynamically in Java, and then pass the button from fragment to fragment (or Activity to Activity, depending on your app).

To declare a Relative Layout with a Button, for example:

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;

public class JavaLayoutActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button myButton = new Button(this);
    RelativeLayout myLayout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    myLayout.addView(myButton);
    setContentView(myLayout);
}
```

This doesn't set the properties or anything, I am just using this as proof of concept.

XML makes things easy with regards to user interface design because you don't have to manage it in code, but this is one case where it is an exception. If you want dynamic interface objects, you need to use Java.

Comment: Can you please explain where to put this code because in my java for my main activity it has lots of fragments and i dont know where to put it in. Also how do i link to other pages. sorry if im asking obvious questions

Comment: Truthfully, I'm at work and don't have time to write an entire app right now. If you don't know what the onCreate method is, you need to read a book or do more internet research. The questions you just asked are easily answerable by either of those things.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating view dynamically you should obtain your view in activity

```
ImageButton button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.firstButton)
```

and assign an onClick listener to id

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // start new Activity here
    }
});
```

You can also do it in xml:

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/firstbutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/homebutton"
    android:onClick="sendMessage"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"/>
```

with such configuration, you should add method in activity:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    // start another activity here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods available in android using which you can go from one Activity to another.

**1.** Use `button.setOnClickListener()`

Create a button in `xml` file.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button" />
```

Now set event listener for the button in your `.class` file

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        //set the event you want to perform when button is clicked
        //you can go to another activity in your app by creating Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, Activity2.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

**2.** Use `<android:onClick="goNext">`

Put the `onClick` as the attribute of the button you have created in `xml` file.

```
<Button
android:id="@+id/button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:text="Button"
android:onClick="goNext" />
```

Now in your `.class` file define an event for that button as,

```
goNext() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext, Activity2.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```